# Check if a Java file compiled successfully using PHP

Tags: java, php, shell, shell-exec

So I need to check out the output of a Java program I am compiling and running using PHP:

```
$output = shell_exec('cd write && javac JavaCode.java && java JavaCode');
```

I don't get anything written to the $output string if the javac command fails. So how do I perform these operations and checks using PHP?

Answer (score 1):

You should be getting `NULL` returned if there was an error.

[From the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php):

> The output from the executed command or NULL if an error occurred or
>   the command produces no output.

Try `var_dump($output)` and see what it returns

Answer (score 0):

append `&& echo 'message'` at the end. Since it's an and, you won't get the message back if any of the commands fail

so

```
$output = shell_exec('cd write && javac JavaCode.java && java JavaCode && echo \'success\'');
```

Answer (score 0):

`exec` can give you return value:

```
  exec('cd write && javac JavaCode.java', $output, $returnValue);
  if ($returnValue == 0) {
      echo 'success';
  } else {
      echo 'compilation failed';
  }
```